# How can I realize a complex communication system in a real time application?

Tags: signal-synthesis

So I am working on a project where I have to model a communication system in MATLAB, then implement it on an FBGA.

My transmitter goes something like that:

```
M        = 4;   N = 1000;
Symb     = randi([0,M-1],N,1);
Mod_Symb = qammod(Symb,M);
```

Now, as you can see the output is complex consisting of four possibilities [+1+1i, +1-1i, -1+1i, -1-1i].  The question is (which I don't know after 4 years mobile com. school!) how do I go from those complex representations to a real time system? I mean, when I want to feed my antenna amplitude data, how do I do that?

Comment: What sort of antenna are you using? What do you feed your antenna? What do you think of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_amplitude_modulation)?

Comment: That sounds fine, but I have a more general question, can use that to any kind of complex signal? I mean, to multiply the real part by cos and the imaginary by sin?

Answer (score 1):

The output of `qammod` in your program is a sequence of amplitudes. If $a_k$ is the real part of the sequence, and $b_k$ the imaginary part, then the QAM baseband signal is: 
\begin{align*}
s_{BB}(t)&=\sum_k a_k p(t-kT_p) + j\sum b_k p(t-kT_p) \\
&= A(t) + jB(t).
\end{align*} In this equation, $T_p$ is the pulse (baud) rate, and $p(t)$ is the pulse shape.

In order to convert this to a real, physical passband signal with carrier frequency $f_c$, you upconvert the baseband signal to frequency $f_c$: $$s_{PB}(t)=\text{Re}(s_{BB}(t)e^{j2\pi f_ct}).$$ While the previous equation is mathematically nice, in practice this is implemented as: $$s_{PB}(t)=A(t)\cos(2\pi f_ct)+B(t)\sin(2\pi f_ct)$$ with possible scale factors to keep the signal energy constant.

Once you have $s_{PB}(t)$, all that remains is amplify it, possibly bandpass filter it to eliminate out-of-band emissions, and connect an antenna.

Note that Matlab works in the discrete-time domain and the signals I've described are continuous time. At some point in your system, you will need to do a digital to analog conversion. Exactly where that will happen depends on many factors. I recommend that you take a look at some common RF architectures, such as heterodyne, homodyne, zero-IF and so on. They can give you ideas on how to implement the analog part of your system. One good reference is "RF System Design of Transceivers for Wireless Communications" by Q. Gu. Another very good book is Steven Tretter's "Communication System Design Using DSP Algorithms: With Laboratory Experiments".